# deleting playlist item using provider after navigator.pop()

Tags: flutter, dart

While viewing a playlist on screen in my app, you have the option to delete the whole playlist.

The current screen being viewed is the playlist detail screen. It has a dependency which is the playlist itself (Drones & AI) that I'm trying to delete.
I need both Nav.pop()'s to complete and the widget tree of this screen to be disposed before I delete the playlist.

[image]

Once you press delete it calls Nav.pop() twice, once to remove the popup modal, and once to navigate back to the playlists page. I need to have completed the transition back to the playlists screen before deleting the playlist thats currently on screen with removePlaylist(), otherwise the dependency for this screen doesn't exist while it's still in view, hence the error. Currently, during transition to the previous screen you can see an error being thrown as the item gets deleted but is still partially displayed on screen. The item doesn't exist anymore obviously which is why the error is being thrown, but how do I avoid this error? I've tried using Future.delayed then deleting the item, but the screen is already disposed and the state is unstable at the time of execution.

error: **Bad state: No element**

removePlaylist():

```
class PlaylistsLocal with ChangeNotifier {
  var singleton = Singleton();

  List<Playlist> _items = [];

  List<Playlist> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  void removePlaylist(Playlist item) {
    List<Playlist> newItems = [..._items];
    newItems.removeWhere((Playlist playlist) => item.title == playlist.title);

    savePlaylist(newItems);

    _items = newItems;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Bottom Modal class:

```
class BuildModalBottomPlaylistEdit extends StatelessWidget {
  final Playlist playlist;
  BuildModalBottomPlaylistEdit(this.playlist);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: Singleton.instance.screenSize.height * .21,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 8, 10),
            child: Text(
              playlist.title ,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.edit,
              color: Colors.black87,
            ),
            title: Text('Edit playlist'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.delete,
              color: Colors.black87,
            ),
            title: Text('Delete playlist'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).pop();

              Provider.of<PlaylistsLocal>(context, listen: false)
                  .removePlaylist(playlist);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try moving `Provider.of<PlaylistsLocal>(context, listen:false)` between two pop contexts?

Comment: I think we'll need to see more code in order to debug this.  Namely, the `removePlaylist` method and perhaps also the page we'll land at after the two Nav pops.  I don't believe the Bad State: No element error is caused directly by anything visible in the above code, but perhaps inside `removePlaylist`.

Comment: Yea your rite @Baker. My initial question is quite unclear now that I read it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacob,

I mocked up a Playlists page, a Playlists Detail page, and a ModalDialog that pops up above Detail page where you can delete the playlist.

I've copied your PlaylistsLocal clas, with placeholders for missing interface items (Singleton, savePlaylist).

But, I couldn't get the error you're seeing.

I don't believe the error is related to the popping of the Modal, nor of the DetailPage, as both of those are popped / gone before the `removePlaylist` method is called.  The DetailPage is stateless (in my example below) and doesn't rebuild based on new data.

Whenever you see `Bad State: No element`, this means you're attempting to [call methods on a `List` which is empty and that error will be thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65152071/2301224).  It's a pretty vague error unfortunately.

Here's my mock code, which hopefully you can compare to your own to find out where your error might be coming from.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<PlaylistsLocal>(
        create: (context) => PlaylistsLocal(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
      )
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Playlists', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),
            Expanded(
                flex: 8,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: Provider.of<PlaylistsLocal>(context).items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      Playlist playlist = Provider.of<PlaylistsLocal>(context).items[i];
                      return Container(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: InkWell(
                            child: Text(playlist.title),
                            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlaylistDetailPage(playlist))
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Playlist detail page uses Playlist object for title data
class PlaylistDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Playlist playlist;

  PlaylistDetailPage(this.playlist);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: InkWell(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: Center(
            child: Text('${playlist.title} DETAILS Page\n (click anywhere)'),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () => showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: true,
          builder: (context) => BottomModalPlaylistEdit(playlist),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomModalPlaylistEdit extends StatelessWidget {
  final Playlist playlist;

  BottomModalPlaylistEdit(this.playlist);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(playlist.title),
        content: Text('Playlist details are here'),
        actions: [
          RaisedButton(child: Text('Back'), onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop),
          RaisedButton(child: Text('Delete'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Provider.of<PlaylistsLocal>(context, listen: false)
                  .removePlaylist(playlist);
            },
          )
        ]
    );
  }
}

class Playlist {
  String title;

  Playlist(this.title);

}

class Singleton {}

class PlaylistsLocal with ChangeNotifier {
  var singleton = Singleton();

  List<Playlist> _items = [Playlist('Hairband Hits')];

  List<Playlist> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  void removePlaylist(Playlist item) {
    List<Playlist> newItems = [..._items];
    newItems.removeWhere((Playlist playlist) => item.title == playlist.title);

    savePlaylist(newItems);

    _items = newItems;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void savePlaylist(List<Playlist> items) {
    // Not sure what you do here
  }

  void resetPlaylist() {
    _items = [Playlist('Hairband Hits')];
  }
}
```

To make repeated testing easier, the ListView.builder can be wrapped in a `Consumer` to rebuild the list of Playlists when button resets the Items in the PlaylistsLocal provider.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Playlists', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),
            Expanded(
                flex: 8,
                child: Consumer<PlaylistsLocal>(
                  builder: (context, value, child) => ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: Provider.of<PlaylistsLocal>(context).items.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        Playlist playlist = Provider.of<PlaylistsLocal>(context).items[i];
                        return Container(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: InkWell(
                              child: Text(playlist.title),
                              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlaylistDetailPage(playlist))
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                  )
                )
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Reset'),
                  onPressed: Provider.of<PlaylistsLocal>(context).resetPlaylist,
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know how you make out with the debugging.

Comment: Hey @Baker, Thanks for all your efforts! I'm gonna give you the answer because damn you've gone above and beyond. Unfortunately the way you're displaying the playlists as you delete or reset is slightly different. See in my code I'm INSIDE of a single playlist viewing each item in the playlist as i delete that playlist. Therefore, when the item gets deleted nothing currently in view on the screen exists until it finishes navigating back to the playlist screen. I can successfully delete from the playlist screen as you have. It's deleting from inside a single playlist which is the issue.

Comment: to fix the issue I've added the unfortunate line to my removePlaylist function inside the provider.  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));. This is not what I wanted to do in the end but it does work, because this forces the app to wait until the navigation back to the playlist screen from inside the playlist im deleting is finished before removing it. @Baker

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, the navigation will be made to the playlist screen and after that, it will delete the playlist. This is causing the error.
The possible solution would be after doing the first navigation(removing popup modal), delete the playlist, and then navigate back to the playlist screen.
Move `Provider.of<PlaylistsLocal>(context, listen: false).removePlaylist(playlist);` in between the two `Navigator.of(context).pop();`.

Refer to this code snippet:

```
class BuildModalBottomPlaylistEdit extends StatelessWidget {
  final Playlist playlist;
  BuildModalBottomPlaylistEdit(this.playlist);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: Singleton.instance.screenSize.height * .21,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 8, 10),
            child: Text(
              playlist.title ,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.edit,
              color: Colors.black87,
            ),
            title: Text('Edit playlist'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.delete,
              color: Colors.black87,
            ),
            title: Text('Delete playlist'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Provider.of<PlaylistsLocal>(context, listen: false)
                  .removePlaylist(playlist);
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response @Ankush Chavan, I think I was unclear in my inital writing of the question. I actually need both Nav.pop()'s to finish before removing the playlist from the list. It might be hard to tell from the image i posted, but the playlist is current being displayed with 1 item in the playlist. So when the playlist gets deleted before the second pop() executes the current screen errors out because the playlist its trying to display no longer exists. I hope this clears up any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet.

```
 class BuildModalBottomPlaylistEdit extends StatelessWidget {
      final Playlist playlist;
      BuildModalBottomPlaylistEdit(this.playlist);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: Singleton.instance.screenSize.height * .21,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 8, 10),
                child: Text(
                  playlist.title ,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 16),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.edit,
                  color: Colors.black87,
                ),
                title: Text('Edit playlist'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.delete,
                  color: Colors.black87,
                ),
                title: Text('Delete playlist'),
                onTap: ()aysnc{
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  
                 await Provider.of<PlaylistsLocal>(context, listen: false)
                      .removePlaylist(playlist);
                   Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response @Chizaram Success, I think I was unclear in my inital writing of the question. I actually need both Nav.pop()'s to finish before removing the playlist from the list. It might be hard to tell from the image i posted, but the playlist is current being displayed with 1 item in the playlist. So when the playlist gets deleted before the second pop() executes the current screen errors out because the playlist its trying to display no longer exists. I hope this clears up any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the following logic and remove bad element error -

The UI part is correct. Nothing to change. ie. -

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
await Provider.of<PlaylistsLocal>(context, listen: false)
                      .removePlaylist(playlist);
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Now inside the PlaylistsLocal Provider. You have to do little changes in the remote playlist Function. Add Future.delayed methods Like this -

```
    Future<void> PlaylistsLocal(String? notesId)async  {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), ()async {
    
       // Your Code ---
      
        notifyListeners();
});
}
```

Now you'll not receive any error. Please thumbs up if you like it.

Comment: @jacob blankenship, you can define the avg duration time as Duration(milliseconds: 500) rather than 1 second in most of the scenarios as it will not take more than that.